# Inheriting Java super class and Type Casting

Tags: java, oop, subclass

I have two Classes in Java

```
Class A { void method1(){} }
Class B extends A {  void method2(){} }
```

When I run the following it works fine:

```
Class C {
  public static void main(String [] args){
    A a1  = new A();
    A a2 = new B();
    B b1 = new B();
    ((B)a2).method2();
  }
 }
```

but why the following does not work ?

```
Class C {
  public static void main(String [] args){
    A a1  = new A();
    A a2 = new B();
    B b1 = new B();
    (B)a2.method2();
  }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: What you're attempting to cast is the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Kabir said, you need to first cast the object before calling a method from another object.

It is because Java reads your second statement as:
`(B) (a2.method2();)`

So java tries to use method two in the A object a2, but it can't because there is no `method2()` in that object.

However, when you type cast it (By putting (B) before a2 in parenthesis), it reads it like:

`(Turn a2 into B).method2();`

Which runs fine because it is turning a2 into a B, which includes method 2, beforehand.

In an easy comparison with a math concept, it is like the order of operations on how you calculate values. You wouldn't say `5 + 5 * 2 = 20`, you would say `5 + 5 * 2 = 15`, because it first calculates `5 * 2`, then adds `5`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the method after casting.  You need brackets around a2 i.e.

```
((B)a2).method2();
```

Comment: but why ? because  both the statement are casting it to B